# Laravel 4.2, Artisan::call() ignoring --env option

Tags: laravel-4

I'm building an application that needs to create a new database, perform migrations and seed db data via a web page.

I'm trying to achieve this with the following code in Laravel 4.2. Note, this is within a controller I've setup.

```
Artisan::call("migrate", array(
    "--env" => "production"
));
```

No matter what environment I pass with the "--env" option, the environment that the migration is run on is the current environment that the site is currently running on.  Ie.  If I'm running on my local environment, and I run the above, it will execute the migration on the local environment which isn't what I'm looking to do.

If I run the equivalent command `php artisan --env=production migrate` from the command line, I get the results I'm looking to achieve.  For the time being, I'm getting past this via `passthru()` but I'd like to take advantage of this Artisan facade if I can.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: Depending on Laravel version, see this bug: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12944#issuecomment-214751735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a pleasant way to do it, but it works.

Assuming your Artisan environment is based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and you know the HTTP_HOST that will load your environment then you can set it manually before calling start.php

I used this to define the Artisan environment based on the base_url I was using in a Behat profile. That way I could configure fixture my database before running tests.

```
/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
public static function runFixtures(SuiteEvent $suiteEvent) {

    // Get the environment domain
    $parameters = $suiteEvent->getContextParameters();
    $baseUrl = $parameters['base_url'];
    $urlParts = parse_url($baseUrl);
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $urlParts['host'];

    // Now call start.php
    require_once 'bootstrap/start.php';

    // Call Artisan
    $stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    Artisan::call(
        'migrate:refresh',
        [
            '--seed' => true,
        ],
        new StreamOutput($stream)
    );
}
```

Comment: As a side note to this, you must add base_url to your context parameters, it doesn't copy from your extension parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`--env` is the option to specify application's environment when the application is starting. In other words, if you specify `--env` option, Laravel will use your specified environment instead runs a detecting method in environment detecting method.

So, If you run `artisan` via CLI with `--env` option, In start file, `artisan` can detect `--env` option from `$_SERVER` variable, specify the application environment and run your command.

In contrast, when you call `Artisan::call()`, Laravel will resolve the console application class (`Illuminate\Console\Application`) and run your command. Because your application was started, then `Application` just runs your command without detecting environment. More over, [latest version of `migration` command class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php) use application environment to get a database connection

Therefore, when your call `Artisan::call()` the `--env` option is completely omitted.

Just my opinion. If you really want to avoid using `passthru()` function, you can rename the production database connection name in `app/config/database.php` to unique name e.g. `production` and set your default database connection to your new name. When you want to migrate production database, just call `Artisan::call('migrate', array('--database' => 'production', '--force' => true))` instead of changing the environment.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear - this is not what I'm looking to do.  I want to call a the migrate command on a different environment than the current.  Ie.  I want to run the migrate command on the "production" environment when the site is currently running in the "local" environment.
It seems the --env option gets ignored.

Comment: I'm sorry for my fault. I was figure out why `env` option is not working and I found migration command always use environment from application instance, thus `env` option is omitted.

Comment: the `'--force'=> true` throws a `The "--force" option does not exist.`.. is there another way?

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol Which version did you use? If you use 4.1 or less, just omit it.

Comment: I'm using 4.2, i found that the --force doesn't work for the install command, but it does for the other ones as well as in seeders