# Get the base_url in Behat @BeforeSuite

Tags: php, behat, mink

I'm using Behat and Mink to test an application using the Laravel framework, and I want to use Artisan to set up the database before running the tests.

In order to correctly configure Artisan, I need to know the domain that will be being tested, and therefore which Laravel environment to use. This is listed in behat.yml under the various profiles being used. Eg:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://www.example.com
            ...
daniel:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://example.dev
```

Is it possible to get the value of base_url from @BeforeSuite?

The main problem here seems to be that @BeforeSuite must be static, and therefore has no access to Mink, so I can't just `$this->getMinkParameter('base_url')`.

I can access parameters with `$suiteEvent->getContextParameters()`, so I could duplicate the url there, but is there a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way some hooks work really freaks me out. The parameters are not passed until the context is instantiated, so there's no clean or easy way of getting them in the context before it's actually created. The best thing to do is to use `@BeforeScenario` event with a `databaseReady` flag, something like that:

```
protected static $databaseReady;

/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
public function setupDatabase()
{
    if (!self::$databaseReady) {

        // Set it up…

        self::$databaseReady = true;
    }
}
```

But then I don't know how it's done in Laravel, but most frameworks have a config and bootstrap, including for different environments. It's a good idea to keep those things in there and use a bootstrap script (that can be run from the `@BeforeSuite` hook), which sets up the environment, including the database.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I can't put the whole Artisan/Laravel answer in here but for anyone interested, it'll be a combination of this answer and my earlier answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643449/laravel-4-2-artisancall-ignoring-env-option/26425714#26425714

Comment: Here's a gist to show roughly how it works when you put it all together: https://gist.github.com/Gisleburt/62ce3507eb792c42dfae

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty hack but if you have to do it from the `@BeforeSuite` hook you can get it like this:

```
use Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Configuration\ConfigurationLoader;
$config = new ConfigurationLoader('BEHAT_PARAMS', getcwd() . '/behat.yml'))->loadConfiguration();
$baseUrl = $config[0]['extensions']['Behat\\MinkExtension']['base_url'];
```

Comment: This would prevent you entering @BeforeScenario multiple times. Neither way is particularly clean, but I like them both. :)