# Calling Artisan Commands from other Artisan Commands using different .env

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use `.env.testing` and I read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration):

> You may also create a .env.testing file. This file will override the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing Artisan commands with the --env=testing option.

I have an artisan command that should create my testing database. The command is triggered using `php artisan testdb:fresh` and [calling another command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands) in his handle method:

```
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->isProduction()) {
        $this->errorMessageTestingDatabase();
        return;
    }

    $this->call('migrate:fresh', ['--env' => 'testing',  '--seed' => true]);
}
```

However, it seems that the `--env=testing` flag is ignored. I get a failure to connect to db exception.

However, if I run the command by

```
php artisan testdb:fresh --env=testing
```

It works. It it not possible to pass an `env` flag when calling an Artisan command withing an Artisan command?

Comment: Does the  `--seed` get executed properly? If so it might be because the `--env` is not in scope for `migrate:fresh`.

Comment: @RobBiermann when I don't pass `--env=testing` it fails on the db connection. When I pass it, seed gets executed.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643449/laravel-4-2-artisancall-ignoring-env-option?

Comment: @RobBiermann no thanks for telling me, mine is a duplicate

Comment: I guess you could 'solve` it by using `exec('php artisan migrate:fresh --env=testing --seed=true')` since this code does not get anything injected by end-users

Answer (score 0):

I think `php artisan testdb:fresh --env=testing` is the only simple way to go, but that puts your `env` on `testing` for all sub-commands(which you might not want).

To do this for individual commands, update the config of the app by overriding the required setting like so(there could be more keys that you need to switch around in stead of only `DB_DATABASE`):

```
$testEnv = [];
//load .env.testing and make a clean key value pair
$testEnvArray = explode("\n", file_get_contents(base_path('.env.testing'))); 
foreach($testEnvArray as $row) {
    $columns = explode('=',$row);
    if(count($columns) === 2)
        $testEnv[$columns[0]] = $columns[1];
}
//Now you have access to test env keys.
config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => $testEnv['DB_DATABASE']]);//override.
...
$this->call('migrate:reset');
... //Put code here that needs test env settings.
config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => env('DB_DATABASE')]);//Reset.
...//Put code here that needs normal env settings.
```

Comment: Has anyone else been able to get this to work?  The subsequent `$this->call('install')` command I run after `config([...])` ignores the newly created and config'd DB.

https://gist.github.com/th3coop/7b1e2ce758dd15da04c85c5da2f7e518#file-runtestscommand-php-L61

Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parameters for an alternative solution.

```
if ($this->input->getOption('env') != 'testing') {
    $this->alert('The {--env=testing} parameter is required');
    return false;
}
```